# Как в слайдере slick реализовать переключение активного слайда по клику на клон?

Tags: javascript, плагин

На сайте есть слайдер (изображение). Реализован через `slick` . На слайдер подвязаны элементы контента на странице, то есть слева текст и снизу переключаются в зависимости от активного слайда (который в центре не прозрачный). А реализовать чтобы при клике мышкой на не активный слайд (справа или слева прозрачные которые) изображение и слайд перемещали соответственно в центр, то есть становились активными и соответственно переключался контент (это момент думаю у самого получится реализовать).
Или может кто посоветует как это реализовать по другому.
И еще, если слайдер зациклен на инфинити, то при переходе с последнего слайда в цепочке на первый происходит дергание,он с паузой меняется, причем не важно изображение это или просто фоном бэкграунд поставить. От чего так может быть и как избежать проблемы?
Буду признателен.[image: пример слайдера]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если представить, что у вас есть `<div>` класса `gallery`, на который присоединен slick, и внутри которого находятся `<div>` класса `item` с картинками, то делается так:

```
$(".gallery .item").on("click", function() {
  const index = $(this).attr("data-slick-index");
  $(".gallery").slick("slickGoTo", index);
});
```

[Пример](https://codepen.io/nsmcan/pen/KEOvjB) (из ответа на другой вопрос)

По-поводу дергания - это до сих пор не исправленная ошибка в slick. Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/961312/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0-slick-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: Спасибо большое!